# Why is taking notes in Friday-prayer sermon disallowed/prohibited/haram in Islam?

Tags: sharia, hadith, practical-islam, sunnah, khutbah

I have heard numerous times that taking note on Friday Jummah sermon is discouraged. I do not really understand the reason why? People who claim its not allowed because it will be a type of innovation.

What did I just innovate? I have attended Jummah throughout the years. I have even dosed off during the listening to the Jummah because of which I didn't know what was said. However, for couple of times, I took notes when listening to the Jummah sermon and I found that it boosted my concentration towards the Jummah sermon and for the first couple of times I actually remembered what was said in sermon.

So I wonder, is taking note really a type of innovation/Bidah?

Clear reference from Quran and Sunnah would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not haram ...

the aim of forbidding anything during Jummah sermon is to focus and under stand what Emmam is talking about.

taking notes is type of concentrating on what Emmam is talking about so it's not haram and there's no any reference telling us that :)

Reference

---

I don't have the English version of that Hadith but I'll give you the [link of the Arabic one](http://www.dorar.net/hadith?skeys=%D8%B3%D9%83%D8%AA+%D8%B9%D9%86+%D8%A7%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%A1&st=a&xclude=)

and I'll translate the meaning of it:

God has imposed ordinances so don't lose them, put limits so don't exceed  them, forbade things so  don't violate them and and kept silent about things not to forget but mercy for you then do not search them.

Alaam Almowqeen for Ibn Qayem AlJawzeyyah 1/221

Comment: Jazaklahir, would you able to find anything or fatwa regarding this?

Comment: Reference has been add :)